# Cassandra CQL3 conditional insert/update

Tags: cassandra, conditional-statements, updates, cql3, nosql

I have a list of unordered events and my task is to store first and last occurrences for them.

I have following column family in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
   event_name TEXT,
   first_occurrence BIGINT,
   last_occurrence BIGINT,
   PRIMARY KEY (event_name)
);
```

So if I have an event with the name "some_event" and occurrence with 123456, what I want to do is something which in MySQL terms would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO events (event_name, first_occurence, last_occurence)
VALUES ('some_event', 123456, 123456)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
     first_occurrence = LEAST(first_occurrence, 12345), 
     last_occurrence = GREATEST(last_occurrence, 123456)
```

I was going to use lightweight transactions in Cassandra  to accomplish it, like this:

```
INSERT INTO events(event_name, first_occurrence, last_occurrence) VALUES ('some_event', 12345, 12345) IF NOT EXISTS;
UPDATE events SET first_occurrence = 123456 WHERE event_name='some_event' IF first_occurrence > 123456;
UPDATE events SET last_occurrence = 123456 WHERE event_name='some_event' IF last_occurrence < 123456;
```

But as it turns out, CQL3 does not allow < and > operators in lightweight transactions IF clause.

So my question is, what is the pattern for doing such conditional updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of cassandra are you running?  Support for non-equal conditions with LWTs was added in 2.1.1 via [CASSANDRA-6839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6839):

```
cqlsh:test> UPDATE events SET first_occurrence = 123456 WHERE event_name='some_event' IF first_occurrence > 1;

[applied]
-----------
  True
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was for.
I'm currently running DataStax community 2.0.9. That means I need to switch to "development" branch

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra does not do read before write with only 2 exceptions - [counters](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters) and "[lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0)". As a result you will not be able to reliably implement your scenario directly in Cassandra. Even if you read the values out and then make an update based on these values, you may overwrite someone else's changes, since there is no locking and isolation in Cassandra, and eventual consistency makes it even worse.

So if you need to implement something like this, you will need to do it outside of Cassandra. Create a synchronization layer which will provide a central point for Cassandra writes, and make this layer responsible for the logic. Just make sure that no writes are making it around this layer.

Comment: Well, I don't see big difference between IF column = values and IF column < value comparisons. So I still think there might be  a way around with lightweight transactions

Comment: You're missing the point. It is not about a difference between equals and not equals, it is about the fact that you don't know the values in the database when you're inserting or updating. For this reason INSERT is a synonym of UPDATE in Cassandra. Out of 4 ACID properties (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) Cassandra offers only 2 - A and D. Your example needs a minimum of one more property - Isolation, maybe Consistency too. That is why I say you will have to build something outside of Cassandra that provides these properties.

Comment: I think we are arguing different things here.
Lightweight transactions do work right?
Cassandra somehow does read-before-write thing on lightweight transactions, queries like this:

`UPDATE events SET first_occurrence = 123456 WHERE event_name='some_event' IF first_occurrence = 2345678;`

So I see no technical differences impementing equals and not equals comparisons.

Comment: Ah, accidentally deleted my comment instead of adding on to it.   LWTs provide linearizable consistency for compare-and-set (CAS) operations.  Traditionally, a CAS operation requires that the expected value be equivalent to the current value to apply the change.  CASSANDRA-6839 (2.1.1+) allows you to use >,< and other comparisons, added an answer for this.